# Determine card type from ATR

Tags: nfc, smartcard, rfid, pcsc, contactless-smartcard

Is it possible using ATR to determine whether I have ISO14443A or ISO14443B type card? If yes, how?

Answer (score 9):

As [mictter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440731/mictter) correctly [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23423380/2425802), a *real* AT**R** only exists for ISO 7816 contact cards. I can follow the argumentation that the ISO 14443 equivalent could be the ATQA/ATQB as this is the first answer you get from tags after activation, though I would rather say that the equvalent of the ATR is a combination of ATQA + SAK + ATS (for Type A) and a combination of ATQB + Answer to ATTRIB (for Type B).

Regarding the ATR *you* see, I assume that this is a PC/SC-emulated ATR according to the [PC/SC specification](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/).

For smartcards (ISO 14443-4 transport protocol) this ATR would have the form

```
3B 8n 80 01 T[1]..T[n] xx
```

with `T[1]` to `T[n]` being

1. the ATS historical bytes for ISO 14443 Type A, or
2. a concatenation of the ATQB application data (`T[1] T[2] T[3] T[4]`), the ATQB protocol information field (`T[5] T[6] T[7]`) and the ATTRIB MBLI field (`T[8]`).

So you might be able to do some form of matching to *guess* if it is a Type A or B smartcard. I.e. if *n* == 8 and the parameters in `T[1]` to `T[n]` match something that you expect for those fields of a Type B card. Still I doubt that you will get reliable results for arbitrary cards.

For contactless memory cards, the situation is certainly better. For these cards, the emulated ATR looks like this:

```
3B 8n 80 01 T[1]..T[n] xx
```

with `T[1]` to `T[n]` containing an application identifier presence indicator (tag `4F`). So `T[1]` to `T[n]` typically look something like this:

```
80 4F yy A000000306 ss nnnn 00000000
```

with `ss` identifying the card's protocol:

```
0x01: ISO 14443-1 Type A
0x02: ISO 14443-2 Type A
0x03: ISO 14443-3 Type A
0x05: ISO 14443-1 Type B
0x06: ISO 14443-2 Type B
0x07: ISO 14443-3 Type B
```

and `nnnn` identifying the card name (see the [PC/SC specifications](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/) for a full list).

Comment: updated source: 3.2.3.10.8     http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/html/pcsc3_v2.01.09/

Comment: hello, where can I find list of card's protocols?

Answer (score 4):

ATR exists for contact smartcards only. For contactless cards, its equivalent is called ATQ, and it comes in two variations: ATQ-A and ATQ-B, for each of the two ISO14443 types.

So the way I'd recommend to go is:

- The reader sends both REQ-A and REQ-B, polling to see if there are contactless cards in range.
- If a card responds with REQ-A, it is Type A; or if it's REQ-B, it is Type B.

The contactless reader's drivers should pass on this information to your software.
I recommend you get hold of a copy of ISO 14443-3 standard, it explain the initial steps of the card discovery and anticollision protocol, so you can see the differences between types A and B.

Answer (score 1):

@haythem souissi

You can find list of card's in pcsc3_v2.01.09_sup (http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.01.09_sup.pdf)

Comment: Link only answer are not valid answer on stackoverflow